# Override summary.phtml template

Tags: magento-2.1, template, overrides, review

I want to override the summary.phtml template `(vendor/magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml)` with a custom module.

The template is overridden in the `catalog_product_view.xml` layout file with this  code:

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
  <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" template="Vendor_Catalog::review/helper/summary.phtml"/>
</referenceContainer>
```

My template is well displayed but the data of the block is not accessible. I ***cannot use the default block methods (getReviewsUrl, etc)***.

I have tested this method but my custom template is not loaded:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Catalog::review/helper/summary.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Do I have to override the block? Is there another way?

Answer (score 0):

**There are no need to add call block under  reference contaniater name**

```
 <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" template="Vendor_Catalog::review/helper/summary.phtml"/>
```

***under***

`<referenceContainer name="content"></referenceContainer>`

### **Just do this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page layout="1column" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
    <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" >
        <arguments>
            <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">Vendor_Catalog::review/helper/summary.phtml</argument>
        </arguments>
    </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

Comment: I have already tried this method but my custom template is not loaded.

Comment: I also tried with the setTemplate xml method, same problem.