# Magento 2: summary.phtml override not working

Tags: magento2, overrides, template-override

I am trying to override summary.phtml file so I can change the functionality of the review button which is below product title, ex:'3 reviews' & 'add new review'.

File: summary.phtml

File Path:

> Magento/module-review/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml

I already override form.phtml to customize my review form, so here is my xml.

File: default.xml

File Path:

> SimpleMagento/ReviewCustomer/view/frontend/layout/default.xml

```
<referenceContainer name="content">
   <referenceBlock name="product.review.form">
      <action method="setTemplate">
        <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">SimpleMagento_ReviewCustomer::form.phtml</argument>
      </action>
   </referenceBlock>
   <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" >
      <arguments>
          <argument name="template" xsi:type="string">SimpleMagento_ReviewCustomer::helper/summary.phtml</argument>
      </arguments>
   </referenceBlock>
</referenceContainer>
```

override summary.phtml File Path:

> SimpleMagento/ReviewCustomer/view/frontend/templates/helper/summary.phtml

after many try its still load core summary.phtml file, not mine.
What I am doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: In which xml file you found product.info.review block ? you have mention this name reference block

Comment: @user55548 I am following answer: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/186431/override-summary-phtml-template

Comment: In this answer, you can see in comment section problem is not solve. You can not use any name in reference block. This should be available. Try to use any existing block name.

Comment: @user55548 can I use product.review.form which I already use?

Comment: yes, check with that.

Comment: @user55548 nothing change, still the load core file

Comment: I think this is because summery.phtml file not called from xml. I have just checked, it called from vendor/magento/module-review/Block/Product/ReviewRenderer.php Try to override this file in your custom module and remove whole <referenceBlock name="product.info.review" > block form default.xml. I am not sure this works but try this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102068/discussion-between-sagar-parikh-sgr-and-user55548).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this by plugin using this below way :

> app/code/Vendor/Module/etc/frontend/di.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright 2015 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type  name="Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer">
       <plugin name="custom_review_template" sortOrder="20" disabled="false" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\CustomReviewRender"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

> app/code/Vendor/Module/Plugin/CustomReviewRender.php

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

class CustomReviewRender {

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http
     */
    protected $request;

    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http $request
    ) {
        $this->request = $request;
    }

    public function beforeSetTemplate(
        \Magento\Review\Block\Product\ReviewRenderer $subject,
        $result
    ) {
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_product_view') {
            return 'Vendor_Module::custom_summary.phtml'; // For product view page => In core Magento_Review::helper/summary.phtml display
        }
        if ($this->request->getFullActionName() == 'catalog_category_view') {
            //return 'Vendor_Module::custom_short_summary.phtml';
            return $result; // For product listing page => In core Magento_Review::helper/summary_short.phtml display
        }
        return $result;
    }

}
```

Now, create phtml file based on your requirement.